# Use php inside HTML mailto link

Tags: php, html, mailto

I am using HTML mailto link and would like to use php inside to display $_SESSION[''] information on the email.

```
        <p>You do not currently have permission to access this tool.</p>
        <p>Please contact admin at
        <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?
        &subject=Requesting%20access%20to%20the%20page_access%20tool
        &body=Hi,%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20is%20<?php$_SESSION['email']?>.%20Please%20provide%20me%20access%20to%20the%20tool.">
        uas.hub@gmail.com</a>
        to request access to this page.</p>
```

Currently this is shown in the email:
This is `<?php$_SESSION['email']?>`. Please provide me access to the tool.

How can I display only the email and not all the php code?

Comment: Basic question, but is the file a .php file running on a server? Because php needs to be parsed server side. You'd also need to echo that variable in order to display it or use short tags like for example `<?= $_SESSION['email']; ?>`

Comment: Apart from other issues here you 1. need to  use valid syntax, so a whitespace following the `<?php ` opening tag and 2. you need to actually output something: `<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>`. The more elegant variant using "short tags" would be `<?= $_SESSION['email'] ?>`, _if short tags are enabled in your php environment_ ...

Comment: Yes, it is a php file running on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `echo` in your code.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>
```